# Convergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {\sqrt n}\sin(\frac 1 n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the series: $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac 1{\sqrt n} \sin\left(\frac1n\right)$ converge?

I think we can do this: $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}\sin(\frac 1 n) \sim \frac 1 {\sqrt n}\frac 1 n=\frac 1 {n^{1.5}}$ and we know that its converging since the exponenet is $>1$.

But when I'm trying the limit comparison test with $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ I get that the series actually diverges like $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ does...

So is there another way to do this without the $\sim$ I did above?

Note: no integral test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sin x < x$ for all $x > 0$, your series is dominated by $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-3/2}$, which converges.

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

$$0\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\,\sin\frac{1}{n}\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}=\zeta(3/2).$$
To provide an explicit bound for $\zeta(3/2)$, notice that:
$$\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{2}{\sqrt{n-\frac{1}{2}}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{2}}}$$
implies, by telescopic summation,
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}} \leq \sqrt{8}.$$

Comment: We haven't covered Zeta...

Comment: @GinKin: take it just as a conventional name for $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, that is converging.

Comment: So writing $\zeta$ there is just Jack showing off.

Answer (score 2):

Consistently to @kobe's short way, you could use the following facts:

> Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}~n^pu_n=A$. Then:
>
> - If $p>1$ and $A$ is finite then $\sum u_n$ converges.
> - If $p\le1$ and $A\neq0$ or $A=\infty$ then $\sum u_n$ diverges.

Now, take for example $p=3/2$.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison test with $1/\sqrt{n}$ doesn't work because:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{{\sin(1/n) \over \sqrt{n}}  \over 1/\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin {1 \over n}=0$$

Hence the limit comparison test doesn't apply.

Comment: Ah right, well it doesn't work with comparing to $\sin \frac 1 n$ either.

Comment: No, because then the limit is $0$ and that case is excluded from the test.

Comment: You probably mean $\sum_{k} \sin (\frac{1}{k})$ doesn't exist

Comment: @Alex why? if the index starts from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: I mean the infinite sum diverges, but the limit itself converges to 0 of course

Comment: Yes, I got confused, sorry, I edited my answer now.